# SQL Server Disabling All Triggers - Cannot find the object "XXXX" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions

Tags: sql-server, permissions, database-permissions

I'm trying to run this command in SQL Server:

```
disable trigger all on MYDB
```

This is failing for me.  The account I'm logged into has access to MYDB and I've pretty much giving it every single permission available (it's a local DB and my account only, so this is OK).  I don't understand why it's telling me it can't find MYDB for this?  I've done this before.  Also note: I can select from the database, update, and run a grant statement (such as granting execution of a proc).  I can also disable triggers manually...

So why does this fail?  I was able to do it before...

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the actual error message?  I'm sure it doesn't say `XXXX`.

Comment: Replace XXX with the database name and its exactly the same.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? DISABLE TRIGGER all'
```

To enable all triggers, you can use following statement

```
sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? ENABLE TRIGGER all'
```

Comment: Note - if your database is case sensitive then you'll have to use sp_MSforeachtable

Comment: I had to use `exec` in front of the stored proc, for example `exec sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? DISABLE TRIGGER all';`

Comment: Worked! One note though. In Azure SQL there is no sp_msforeachtable, so you'll have to create it. Look into https://gist.githubusercontent.com/metaskills/893599/raw/003b0d5ffa8e9aa6d1f600a89ff5f60438044c5c/gistfile1.sql

Answer (score 0):

```
use MYDB;
disable trigger all on DATABASE;
```

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, but for some reason, all triggers are enabled.... strange.

Comment: Strange... This usage is declared by Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189748.aspx , I just correct your syntax.

Comment: I know, I thought so to.  It does work, but refresh and the triggers are still enabled... not sure why...

Comment: Looking at those docs, I'm guessing this will only work for triggers that are declared on a database scope, and not those which are declared on table events.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why Yuck deleted their answer. From [DISABLE TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189748.aspx):

> **object_name** 
>    Is the name of the table or view on which the DML trigger trigger_name was created to execute.

That is, you can't provide a database name to this statement. Whilst the `MYDB` *database* exists, there *isn't* an object within it called `MYDB`.

Comment: Yuck removed his answer because of my comment.  DISABLE TRIGGER ALL on DATABASE doesn't do anything for some reason... says success, but all triggers are enabled.  But yes structurally that makes sense with DISABLE TRIGGER.